# How does the ACM ICPC Online Judge prevent malicious attacks?

Tags: security

I've spent more than a few hours humbling myself on the [ACM ICPC's problem set archive](http://acm.uva.es/problemset/), and I've wondered how the online judge is able to compile and run source code from any user and prevent malicious attacks to their system.

Are the compiled binaries run from some kind of limited sandbox? How would one go about setting up this kind of sandbox? What OS would you use? How would you launch a user's compiled executable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run it in a Linux chroot jail, or link it against a libc that doesn't implement any file I/O.

Comment: What exactly is a chroot jail?

Comment: It's an environment available in some UNIX systems that lets a program run without having any access to the full filesystem. Processes running inside the jail see a certain subdirectory as their root directory, and cannot access anything outside of it.  

Specifically, a system call sets the fake root directory and all child processes inherit it.

Answer (score 6):

The programs are run in a chrooted jail with a limited run time.  Judge computers are distributed across a number of servers to help prevent a single point of failure or DOS attacks.

I am a regional contest admin.

Comment: could you elaborate on what a chrooted jail is?

Comment: It will be great if anybody can explain about it a bit more. Do all libraries required at run time by gcc  need to included in that jailed area?

Answer (score 5):

The easy way of forming sandbox (assuming Linux as server OS, which is common for ACM) is using (ancient) chroot, or some kernel patches. There are some more advanced sandboxing techniques in the kernel now, e.g.:

- [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) - Linux 2.6.12+ - process can ask OS using special `prset` call, to limit process capabilities to: exiting, reading and writing already opened files. OS will refuse to do any other system call effectively isolating program from outer world. And there is no way to reset these capabilities back. (This solution may break some progressive languages like python,perl,ruby etc which wants to load some plugins during run time.)
- namespace isolation - [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). chroot is a program to change (isolate) only filesystem namespace, and there are other namespaces, e.g. network or process. Using cgroups we can limit more than possible using only chroot.

Some kernel patches, written for online judges, e.g. 
* ejudge.ru has patches to 2.6.38.8, 3.4.15, 3.7.5; and also some solutions for Windows. (The site in russian.) I think, this system may be used in some contests in Russia, not sure about 1/4 ACM ICPC.

Some judge systems uses `ptrace()` syscall - in other words, they acts like debugger for the tested program and judge can control all syscalls, and can cancel any of them without passing it into kernel.

And there are open-source judge systems, e.g. https://openjudge.net/ (libsandbox)

Answer (score 0):

I think they don't run any code. Sometimes there is this error "Restricted function" for example when you try to read or write a file "ofstream" & "ifstream" in c++